# Why this simple passport-local authentication doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

This minimalistic implementation of local passport strategy, always redirect me to /failure:

```js
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const session = require('express-session');

var user = {username:"joe", password:"parmesano", id:34};
console.log(user);

passport.use(new LocalStrategy( (username, password, done) => { 
    done(null, user);
}));

passport.serializeUser( (user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser( (id, done) => {
    done(null, user)
});

const app = express();

app.use(session({ secret: 'jamalaja', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/failure', successRedirect: '/success' }));

app.listen(3000);
```

Should not I be sent to / success?

Comment: I probe it with: curl -X POST -H "Conten-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"meda", "password":"ajana"}' localhost:3000/

Answer (score 1):

I get the /success redirect if I add body-parser middleware:

`app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

And test it with the command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=meda&password=ajana' localhost:3000/
```